# Starting a screen session from within another screen session

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I made a script, that runs in a screen session.
This script shall run several new scripts in a new screen, if they are down.
(They crash frequently, so this is necessery).
But for some reason, the script does not start a new screen. It is no error seen on the screen, when the script tries to start the new screen and the script does not abort work.
So I think there is a problem to launch a new screen from within another screen.

So, how can I start a new screen session from within another screen?

Comment: Well, I know, that it is possible, but I did not find out, how...

Comment: Ok, after testing it again and again, I do not think, it is a problem with the screens. When I run the script as a job and not as a screen, I end up with the same problem. I do not know, what the problem is... First, I call a script, that is the first screen, it starts multiple other scripts. Those other scripts does not run the new screen anymore, but do a normal echo call... I do not know, what could be the problem... even to sudo the script does not help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out... The second screen was terminating itself immidiatly after creating... Don't know why, but that's the reason... Solved it complicated, but it work now!